# Inserting value in one column from another table mysql

Tags: php, mysql

**school**

```
+-----+-----------+----------+
| id  | the_photo | column3  |
+-----+-----------+----------+
| 11  |     NULL  |     abc  |
| 22  |     NULL  |     asf  |
| 33  |     NULL  |     asag |
+-----+-----------+----------+
```

**school_images**

```
+-----+-----------+-------+    
| id  | school_id | photo |
+-----+-----------+-------+
| 1   | 11        |  1    |
| 2   | 22        |  0    |
| 3   | 33        |  1    |
+-----+-----------+-------+
```

...

Need to insert values into the_photo column of school only if photo value = 1 for school_images like this:

**School**

```
+-----+-----------+
| id  | the_photo |
+-----+-----------+
| 11  |     1     |
| 22  |     NULL  |
| 33  |     3     |
+-----+-----------+
```

Is there a simple query that can be written to do this for all rows? For one row i know how to insert it but how can i auto inert for multiple rows.

Comment: Insert or update the value in another table?

Comment: why do you need to do this?

Comment: @gvgvgvijayan - insert value in school

Comment: @Strawberry - it was missed requirement so now need to rectify.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE school AS s, school_images AS si SET s.the_photo = si.id WHERE s.id = si.school_id AND si.photo = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you're looking for: [SELECT INTO](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html).
Taken from the link:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_temp2 (fld_id)
    SELECT tbl_temp1.fld_order_id
    FROM tbl_temp1 WHERE tbl_temp1.fld_order_id > 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

**BEWARE!!** **This answer is good only if you want to perform the above requested action upon a new insertion. Otherwise, you will need a different strategy**

you should have something like this:

1. Select all you values from `school_images` then foreach them:

   `foreach($result as $res) {
      if($res['photo'] == 1) {
         // see step 2
      } else {
        // see step 3
      }
    }`
2. if you have the value 1 in school_photos then:

`INSERT INTO school (the_photo, colum3) VALUES ($res['id'], $some_value)`

3. if you don't have it, then perform a normal insert like you did by now.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use inner join to achieve that.

```
 Update School inner join school_images on School.id = school_images.school_id and photo=1
set the_photo = school_images.id ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use an INNER JOIN to join `school` with `school_images`:

```
UPDATE
  school INNER JOIN school_images
  ON school.id = school_images.school_id
     AND school_images.photo=1
SET
  school.the_photo=school_images.id
```